# Standing water in water softener, do I need to replace my newly installed water softener?

Tags: plumbing, water-softener

I purchased the [Rheem Preferred 32,000 Grain Water Softener](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rheem-Preferred-32-000-Grain-Water-Softener-RHS32/314448295) from Home Depot (with an extended warranty) about a month ago and had it professionally installed by my plumber. However, I noticed recently that there was a lot of standing water in the unit.

I live in Las Vegas, Nevada and my water softener is installed in my garage. The drain line goes up to the second floor into my laundry room. However, given that this unit does not have a pump and water has to travel more than 9 feet in the air, is this causing the regeneration cycle to not have enough time for it to be extracted, resulting in the water flowing back into the tank? It's not uncommon for houses in Vegas to have the drain line connected to the laundry room in the 2nd floor. When I called support, they told me that the drain line should not be more than 9 feet in the air, but this unit is very similar to my old Whirlpool softener unit that I replaced many years ago.

Here are some photos I took recently showing that there is standing water and the drain line from my laundry room in the 2nd floor after manually starting a cycle:
[image]
[image]

Comment: `water has to travel more than 9 feet in the air` and `drain line should not be more than 9 feet in the air` ... doesn't that give you a hint?

Comment: I thought there might be another reason because my plumber has installed similar water softeners with the same setup where the laundry room is on the second floor and the softener is installed in the garage without any problems. I don't think the unit is faulty but the only thing I can do is call the manufacturer and have them send someone out. Otherwise, I would have to consider a different solution for my house such as salt-free water softener/conditioner.

Comment: it is up to you to determine where the water is leaking from ... that cannot be determined by someone remotely ... use a wet vac to remove the water and watch as the water refills ... sprinkle a pinch of sawdust, or pepper onto the water to reveal any currents in the water